# Weekday captions with the TikZ library "calendar"

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar

I use the TikZ library `calendar` to produce a week list. The code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}
    \tikz\calendar[dates=2011-02-01 to 2011-02-last,week list];
\end{document}
```

However, I want to add abbreviated captions for the weekdays (M, T, W, ...) in the first line of the week list:

```
 M  T  W  T  F  S  S
    1  2  3  4  5  6
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13
14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28
```

I couldn't find any option to the `\calendar` macro which produces this effect. Is there any other solution to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no way of doing this with a single option, but the following code is a way of getting the weekday headings in a way that keeps all options of the `week list` calendar. It adds the style `day letter headings` (which in this form only makes sense to use with the `week list` style). The style of the headings can be set with the option `day headings`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\makeatletter%
\tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
\tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
\tikzstyle{day letter headings}=[
    execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
      \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@ya}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
      \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}
      \foreach \d/\l in {0/M,1/T,2/W,3/T,4/F,5/S,6/S} {
        \pgf@xa=\d\pgf@xa%
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa}%
        \pgftransformyshift{\pgf@ya}%
        \node[every day,day heading]{\l};%
      } 
    }{}%
  }%
]

\makeatother%

\begin{document}
    \tikz\calendar[dates=2011-02-01 to 2011-04-last,
        week list,
        month label above centered,
        day xshift = 0.8cm,
        day headings=orange,
        day letter headings
    ];
\end{document}
```

[image: Week list calendar with single letter day headings]

Comment: BTW: A slash is missing between `\d` and `\l` (it should be `\foreach \d/\l in {0/M,1/T,2/W,3/T,4/F,5/S,6/S} {`, otherwise, I get an error message).

Comment: @diabonas Thanks! I've added the missing slash. Interestingly, it worked fine without it for me, although according to the manual it shouldn't. Maybe something changed in recent versions of pgf.