# vertical week list in TikZ calendar

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar

I read about `week list` in the PGF/TikZ manual, but I couldn't find an example that arranges the days of the week vertically:

```
June 1997

M   2  9 16 23 30
T   3 10 17 24
W   4 11 18 25
T   5 12 19 26
F   6 13 20 27
S   7 14 21 28
S 1 8 15 22 29
```

Could you help me with an example of how to create a week list arrangement like this?

Comment: Maybe also have a look at the http://ctan.org/pkg/calxxxx and http://ctan.org/pkg/calxxxx-yyyy packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a new style `vertical week list`, which is adapted from the `week list` style found in the TikZ source code. The day labels are adapted from the answer to [Weekday captions with the TikZ library "calendar"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10186/weekday-captions-with-the-tikz-library-calendar).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

 \makeatletter
\tikzstyle{week list}=[%
  execute before day scope={%
    \ifdate{day of month=1}{\ifdate{equals=\pgfcalendarbeginiso}{}
      {%
        % On first of month, except when first date in calendar.
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\tikz@lib@cal@month@xshift}%
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@x}
      }%
    }{}%
  }, 
  execute at begin day scope={%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
    \pgf@y=\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday\pgf@y%
    \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@y}%
  },
  execute after day scope={%
    \ifdate{Sunday}{%
      \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
      \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@x}
    }{}%
  }
]

\tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
\tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
\tikzstyle{day letter headings}=[
    execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
      \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa}
      \foreach \d/\l in {0/M,1/T,2/W,3/T,4/F,5/S,6/S} {
        \pgf@ya=\d\pgf@ya%
        \pgftransformxshift{-\pgf@xa}%
        \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}%
        \node[every day,day heading, anchor=base]{\l};%
      } 
    }{}%
  }%
]
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\calendar[
    dates=1997-06-01 to 1997-06-last,
    week list,
    day letter headings,
    day heading/.style={gray, xshift=-1em},
    month label above left,
    month text=\%mt \%y0
];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use `\pgftransformyshift` for shifting days down. Here's an example style arranging the days vertically:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\tikzstyle{week list downward}=[%
  execute before day scope={%
    \ifdate{day of month=1}{\ifdate{equals=\pgfcalendarbeginiso}{}{%
      \pgftransformxshift{1.5em}}%
    }{}}, 
  execute after day scope={%
    \ifdate{Sunday}{%
      \pgftransformyshift{6em}
      \pgftransformxshift{1.5em}
    }{\pgftransformyshift{-1em}}},
]
\begin{document}
  \tikz\calendar [dates=2012-01-01 to 2012-03-last,week list downward];
\end{document}
```

[image: weekly calender with vertically arranged days]

Comment: Thanks, great example of `\pgftransformyshift`!