# Right to left week list style in tikz calendar

Tags: tikz-pgf, right-to-left, calendar

I found this question [vertical week list in TikZ calendar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39813/vertical-week-list-in-tikz-calendar) and I need to create a similar style `RTL week list` with row for week starting from right side

Here an example with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,positioning}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\def\pgfcalendarmonthname#1{\translate{\ifcase#1\or جانفي\or فيفري\or مارس\or أفريل
\or ماي\or جوان\or جويلية\or أوت\or سبتمبر\or أكتوبر\or نوفمبر\or ديسمبر\fi} }

\pagestyle{empty}


%\tikzstyle{RTL week list}=[??]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[every calendar/.style = {
    month label above centered,
    month text = {\Large{\%mt}},
    }]

\calendar[dates=2018-01-01 to 2018-01-last,week list]if (Friday) [red];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With this output

[image]

What I need is like this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `day xshift=` with some negative spacing amount, please adjust to your personal preferences. The `week list` style uses `day xshift` etc. to separate the individual days, usually with positive values listing days from left to right, negative values reverse the list.

I had to disable the font settings (I don't own the Arabic fonts)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,positioning}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

%\def\pgfcalendarmonthname#1{\translate{\ifcase#1\or جانفي\or فيفري\or مارس\or أفريل
%\or ماي\or جوان\or جويلية\or أوت\or سبتمبر\or أكتوبر\or نوفمبر\or ديسمبر\fi} }

\pagestyle{empty}


%\tikzstyle{RTL week list}=[??]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[every calendar/.style = {
    month label above centered,
    month text = {\Large{\%mt}},
    }]

\calendar[dates=2018-01-01 to 2018-01-last, week list, day xshift=-3ex]if (Friday) [red];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]