# Tikz calendar leads to strange behavior

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar

I need to position the calendar within a tikzpicture (this is a MWE, the original file is much more complex, containing also fading pictures etc, so I really want to do it within the tikzpicture environment). I don't understand why the text disappeares and why I can not center the calendar...

```
\documentclass[11pt,BCOR8mm,final,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[germanb]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

% code von: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10186/weekday-captions-with-the-tikz-library-calendar

\makeatletter%
\tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
\tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
\tikzstyle{day letter headings}=[
execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
  \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@ya}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
  \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
  \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}
  \foreach \d/\l in {0/M,1/D,2/M,3/D,4/F,5/S,6/S} {
    \pgf@xa=\d\pgf@xa%
    \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa}%
    \pgftransformyshift{\pgf@ya}%
    \node[every day,day heading]{\l};%
  } 
}{}%
}%
]

\makeatother%


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[text=black, font=\fontsize{20}{44}\selectfont] at (13,22.7)  {Einladung zur Feldkampagne};

\node[text=black, font=\fontsize{20}{44}\selectfont] at (13,21)  {Schulprojekt 1 / 2017};

\node[text=black, font=\fontsize{20}{44}\selectfont] at (13.0,15.)  {Zeitraum:};


%\begin{center}
    \tikz\calendar[dates=2017-06-01 to 2017-07-last,
    week list,
    month label above centered,
    day xshift = 0.8cm,
    day headings=blue,
    if={(equals=07-10) [nodes={draw,thick}]},
    if={(equals=07-11) [nodes={draw,thick}]},
    if={(equals=07-12) [nodes={draw,thick}]},
    if={(equals=07-19) [nodes={draw,thick}]},
    if={(equals=07-20) [nodes={draw,thick}]},
    if={(equals=07-21) [nodes={draw,thick}]},
    day letter headings
];
%\end{center}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\tikz` is a shortform of `\begin{tikzpicture} .. \end{tikzpicture}`, so you shouldn't use the former inside the latter.

It also doesn't make sense to have a `center` environment inside a `tikzpicture` environment. As far as (La)TeX is concerned, a `tikzpicture` is just a (usually) big rectangular box, and it is positioned on the page just like any other big box, e.g. an `\includegraphics`. You want the `center` environment *outside* the `tikzpicture`.

If you fix those two things your output makes more sense, but the "title" nodes are placed quite badly. Personally I think I would place those few lines as normal text, outside the `tikzpicture`, as in the code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,BCOR8mm,final,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[germanb]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

% code von: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10186/weekday-captions-with-the-tikz-library-calendar

\makeatletter%
\tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
\tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
\tikzstyle{day letter headings}=[
execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
  \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@ya}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
  \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
  \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}
  \foreach \d/\l in {0/M,1/D,2/M,3/D,4/F,5/S,6/S} {
    \pgf@xa=\d\pgf@xa%
    \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa}%
    \pgftransformyshift{\pgf@ya}%
    \node[every day,day heading]{\l};%
  } 
}{}%
}%
]

\makeatother%


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\Huge Einladung zur Feldkampagne

Schulprojekt 1 / 2017 \par}

\bigskip

{\Large Zeitraum: \par}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\calendar[dates=2017-06-01 to 2017-07-last,
    week list,
    month label above centered,
    day xshift = 0.8cm,
    day headings=blue,
    if={(equals=07-10) [nodes={draw,thick}]},
    if={(equals=07-11) [nodes={draw,thick}]},
    if={(equals=07-12) [nodes={draw,thick}]},
    if={(equals=07-19) [nodes={draw,thick}]},
    if={(equals=07-20) [nodes={draw,thick}]},
    if={(equals=07-21) [nodes={draw,thick}]},
    day letter headings
];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your very very valuable hint. And sorry for the delay of my answer, I took part on an excavation in the Kaukasus the last three weeks...